# Select only unique values from a column in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a table like this

```
name|subjects|location
......................     
BUET|CSE|Dhaka
BUET|EEE|Dhaka
RUET|CE |Rajshahi
RU  |CE |Rajshahi
```

here all the rows are distinct.And if I use

```
 $this->db->select('*') and $this->db->distinct()
```

it would select  all the rows of BUET but i only want like this

```
name|subjects|location
......................     
BUET|CSE|Dhaka
RUET|CE |Rajshahi
RU  |CE |Rajshahi
```

That means only the first column must be distinct and select all the columns as usual.And it would work if i use $this->db->select('name') and `$this->db->distinct()`. Then what would be about the other columns??

As my original table has many columns so I want to use `$this->db->select('*')`. I think  `$this->db->distinct()` does not take any column as parameter. It differentiate result based on select. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try like this

```
$this->db->select('DISTINCT `name`'); //You may use $this->db->distinct('name');  
$this->db->select('*');
```

Select the **distinct values by names**.And your SELECT spelt wrong,may be its a typing mistake.And you can also use GROUP BY like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->group_by('name');
```

Comment: does $this->db->distinct('name'); take parameter ?? i am not sure

Comment: IN documentation of CI there is no parameter :(

Comment: You can use $this->db->select('DISTINCT `name`');

Comment: but i want to use this $this->db->select('*') as there are a lot of columns which i dont want to select singly :(

Comment: now it works .Thanks @Gautam2164 for take make me understand :)

Comment: and make sure you have `name` field in your table index.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->group_by('column_name');
        $this->db->from('tbl_name');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

*try this*

Answer (score 2):

You should use group_by in place of distinct.

because distinct will return unique rows. but to have unique column by row you should do group by.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('column names');
$this->db->distinct();
$query = $this->db->get('table name');
$query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $this->db->select('job,id');
   $this->db->group_by('job');
   $query= $this->db->get('technicals')->result_array();
   if(!empty($query)){
       return $query;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: this code return only one job from  repeated job with the same name  works like (distinct) where technicals is my table name and id,job are columns in this table